# How can we retrieve the value associated with that DateTimeIndex in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe and a specific index whose type is `DateTimeIndex`, how can we retrieve the value associated with that index?
Consider the the following code where we have the index of a maximum in a certain range:

```
index = pd.date_range('7-20-2022', '7-21-2022', freq='min')
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(len(index))), index=index)
df_limited = df.loc['7-20-2022'].between_time('14:00', '15:00')
idx  = df_limited.idxmax()
```

**What is the value at `idx`?**

None of `max=df_limited.loc[idx]`, `max=df_limited.iloc[idx]`, or `max = df_limited[(df_limited.index == idx)]` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idx` is a `Series`, you can use its value for indexing:

```
max = df_limited.loc[idx.iloc[0], 0]
```

Result of `print(max)`:

```
-46.80161593790951
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `loc` the value of series

```
df_limited.loc[idx]
Out[470]: 
                               0
2022-07-20 14:06:00 -46.80161594
```